# Pivoting unstructured Data SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

We are reporting on data from a generic form application so my data comes out as the following

| QHierarchy | QText | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | Room | Room1 |
| 1.0.0 | RoomType | Kitchen |
| 1.0.1 | Items |  |
| 1.0.1.0 | Item | Microwave |
| 1.0.1.1 | Item | Fridge |
| 1.0.1.2 | Item | Cooker |
| 1.1 | Room | Room2 |
| 1.1.0 | RoomType | Lounge |
| 1.1.1 | Items |  |
| 1.1.1.0 | Item | Couch |
| 1.1.1.1 | Item | TV |
| 1.2 | Room | Room3 |
| 1.2.0 | RoomType | Lounge |
| 1.2.1 | Items |  |
| 1.2.1.0 | Item | Couch |
| 1.2.1.1 | Item | Lamp |
| 1.2.1.2 | Item | Rug |

I am trying to get my SSRS report to output the following

| Room | Type | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Room1 | Kitchen | Microwave |
| Room1 | Kitchen | Fridge |
| Room1 | Kitchen | Cooker |
| Room2 | Lounge | Couch |
| Room2 | Lounge | TV |
| Room3 | Lounge | Couch |
| Room3 | Lounge | Lamp |
| Room3 | Lounge | Rug |

I figured this would be resolved with some form of matrix to pivot the data however I tried having my items as the rows  (by using answer column and filtering to regex the 1.x.x.x) but am a little stumped how i make the matrix traverse backwards up the hierarchy to display the type/room

Comment: What is the source of your data? Is is from SQL Server? If so what version? We'll have to do a little work on it to get it in the right format but I think it's doable, just need to know what we're working with

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server and a version that supports `string_split` (SQL Server 2016 onwards I think) then this should work. If you are using SQL Server but an earlier version, there are loads of string)split type functions around that you could copy and use to create your own function. I have one I used to use back in the SQL2008 days I can share if required.

Below is a full script to do what you want...

It handles `QHierachy` up to 4 positions but could be easily update to support more levels.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (QHierarchy varchar(20), QText varchar(20), Answer varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @data VALUES 
  ('1.0', 'Room', 'Room1'), ('1.0.0', 'RoomType', 'Kitchen'), ('1.0.1', 'Items', ''), ('1.0.1.0', 'Item', 'Microwave'), ('1.0.1.1', 'Item', 'Fridge')
, ('1.0.1.2', 'Item', 'Cooker'), ('1.1', 'Room', 'Room2'), ('1.1.0', 'RoomType', 'Lounge'), ('1.1.1', 'Items', ''), ('1.1.1.0', 'Item', 'Couch')
, ('1.1.1.1', 'Item', 'TV'), ('1.2', 'Room', 'Room3'), ('1.2.0', 'RoomType', 'Lounge'), ('1.2.1', 'Items', ''), ('1.2.1.0', 'Item', 'Couch')
, ('1.2.1.1', 'Item', 'Lamp'), ('1.2.1.2', 'Item', 'Rug')

drop table if exists #t

SELECT 
        *
        , Lvl = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM string_split(QHierarchy, '.')) - 1
        , Item = SUBSTRING((SELECT '.' + [value]
                    FROM (SELECT top 3 * FROM string_split(QHierarchy, '.')) s 
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 100)
        , RoomType = SUBSTRING((SELECT '.' + [value]
                    FROM (SELECT top 2 * FROM string_split(QHierarchy, '.')) s 
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 100) + '.0'
        , Room = SUBSTRING((SELECT '.' + [value]
                    FROM (SELECT top 2 * FROM string_split(QHierarchy, '.')) s 
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 100)
into #t                   
    FROM @data
    WHERE ISNULL(Answer, '') != ''

SELECT r.Answer as Room, t.Answer as RoomType, i.Answer as Item
    FROM #t i 
        JOIN #t t on i.RoomType = t.QHierarchy
        JOIN #t r on i.Room = r.QHierarchy
    WHERE i.lvl = 3
```

You can see it working here... https://dbfiddle.uk/Ixu3_RTG

`Lvl` just counts the number of positions in `QHierarchy`
`Item` takes the first 3 positions from `QHierarchy` and concatenates them into a single string
`RoomType` does a similar thing but only uses the 1st 2 positions and then appends a `.0` to the end as your data does not have a direct relationship between the levels due to having and "Items" group/level in there.
`Room` takes the first 2 positions from `QHierarchy` and concatenates them into a single string

Once that's done it's just a couple of simple joins to get the respective data from each level.

Assuming your data looks like the sample you showed, you should be able to swap the references to `@data` with your real table name.

Now you have a simple dataset for the report to use...